# Check whether child member is NULL

Tags: c++, null, visual-c++-2010

I have this code:

```
class Connection
{
public:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
}

void main()
{
   Connection* session = new Connection();
   //for example
   session->socket_.close() // FATAL ERROR PAGE FAULT
   // How to check whether child member socket_ is null? if(session->socket_ != NULL) - error : no operator != mathes these operands
}
```

When i try `if(session->socket_ != NULL)` - error : no operator != mathes these operands

I Use VS2010

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket_` is not a pointer and so no operator is define to compare it against NULL. Maybe you need to use [is_open](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/is_open.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so how to check whether member is initialized?

Comment: this function is not static as i know, how can i use it if member is not initialized?

Comment: member is not a pointer it is an object. It is initialized during the call of its constructor.